# Ask anonymously on SO

Tags: feature-request

Why we can't ask question anonymously on Stack Overflow ? Why can't we just ask without showing the usercard or reputation?

I think that may:

1. Encourage people to ask more questions without thinking too much about what others might think of them
   (Especially colleagues from workplace, managers, **confidentiality concerns**.)
2. Avoid some 'discrimination' related to reputation.
   (Rarely, good questions get ignored or downvoted just because the user has very low reputation or because he's just new).

Comment: "Encourage people asking more question without thinking too much about what other may think of us" - and why exactly should we encourage that? SO is already overrun with lazy crap questions of people who want others to do their work, that's not something anybody should encourage. Having more questions is only a good thing if the questions are of high quality, which anonymity would probably prevent.

Comment: Do you have evidence to support point 2?

Comment: 1. You use a pseudo, don't share it with your colleagues/managers and who'll know it's you?
2. Good questions from low rep users get downvoted mostly because they are poorly written, not because of the low rep

Comment: Your second point is just another BS argument with absolutely no basis. I have not seen any _good_ question getting downvoted just because the user has no rep. On the contrary, I have seen many bad questions which I downvoted get upvoted again by people who think new users should get a free pass simply because they're new.

Comment: @l4mpi That's hilarious. Low quality questions are constantly posted anyway by people who couldn't care less about the site and will just make a new user when that one gets banned. It's not like the username is personally identifyable. The only reason i can see for people actually wanting usernames is for some sort of personal gratification to fuel their narcisistic personailities. How about hide rep and username, then noone can be discriminated against, good questions and answers will be upvoted, bad ones downvoted.

Comment: @l4mpi: not all managers are ok that you ask questions on SO ( people are from different cultures ... and have different management styles ...)

Comment: @JID it's I have yet to see evidence that any sort of discrimination happens. And while I personally wouldn't have too much of a problem with hiding usernames and rep (I stopped farming rep after I had enough to closevote), that would drive tons of high rep users away from this site. You don't really think people with >300k rep are here to anonymously help others, right?

Comment: What manager/culture would forbid the people doing the work to go out and get the help they need? Using resources like SO to get work done and to improve personal knowledge is an important skill for every programmer.

Comment: @εEridani Sorry, I completely fail to care about your managers. And it's yet another BS argument anyways - if your manager doesn't want you to use SO, then choose a username they won't recognize. But unless they actively monitor SO, the chance of them finding out from the site (as opposed to walking in on somebody who currently types out a question) is abyssimally small anyways.

Comment: If confidentiality is the problem, be a good employee and don't post confidential data on a public site. Posting it anonymously doesn't make it okay. It's not SO's job to prevent people from posting confidential data.

Comment: @l4mpi `You don't really think people with >300k rep are here to anonymously help others, right?` That was sort of my point. To be fair though, i agree with your views on the confidentiality side. As i said the user names are not personally identifiable.

Comment: do I get so many downvots if i just asked " is it possible to ask anonymousley." and tagged my question " asking for features" ?

Comment: @εEridani: That's hard to say. You probably would, if you didn't add a good reason why SO would need the feature.

Comment: It *used* to be possible to post a question anonymously, but they disabled that feature as there were too many questions anyway: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107163/220428

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I think you should need an account and everything works the same way as it does now, except it says anonymous instead of your name and 0 rep.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: thanx for feedback, what I'm really asking for is just for some questions choose to ask anonymosly.( not registration)

Comment: @JID: What would be the point?

Comment: @Cerbrus As much as everyone would say they don't I'm 100% sure people have biases for or against certain users.Tbh i have found myself doing so before.

Comment: @PhilipCrow as I said, "the chance of them finding out from [monitoring] the site (as opposed to walking in on somebody who currently types out a question) is abyssimally small anyways". Adding a way to post anonymously would make absolutely no difference in this case, as the manager would still see their employee asking a question on SO.

Comment: @l4mpi: in the first time I asked about a feature ( don't know why the editer removed and change it to 'discussion' !) if you can't (understand|don't like|*) why some feature are needed it's up to you and that does not mean in any case why others consider theme crucial, context is not universal, immutable and eternal.

Comment: @DanielKelley please tell me what is the difference between the two answers ? besides some styling.

Comment: @εEridani Sorry I have no idea what you are asking me. Maybe you were responding to someone else. My point was what evidence do you have that low rep users are downvoted based on their rep alone, rather than the quality of their questions?

Comment: @DanielKelley: nop 'im responding you, the two answers are a perfect example of my point 2.

Comment: @εEridani I'm still lost. Which questions? And given the sheer volume of questions on StackOverflow how can you possibly draw a conclusion from 2 questions?

Comment: Btw, If you create a new account, let it be as user****** and keep the profile blank, you get your anonymity. And in your 2nd point, the new user can also be a **she**. (thats an example of ironic discrimination)

Comment: @εEridani the fact that you can't comprehend the difference between the answers by jon and Philip does not prove anything. And it does not matter if you consider your proposed feature "crucial", it would still make the site worse.

Comment: @l4mpi being unable to distinguish what is asked in the question and what is suggested to support the point does not prouve nothing! just notice that I use"may","rarely ".... in the other side you're so confident about your arguable arguments

Answer (score 17):

I'm opposed to the idea of anonymising questions. To address your two objectives:

> Encourage people to ask more questions without thinking too much about what others might think of them (Especially colleagues from workplace, managers, **confidentiality concerns**.)

I think that this is **actively counter-productive**. In my opinion, people asking question on SO *should* think about what others think of them; it might make them less likely to ask lazy questions they could and should be answering for themselves, or put more effort into reading and following the guidance. It's not like there's any kind of question shortage on SO; what we want to encourage is *high quality* content, which in my view tends to come from people who *want* to be taken seriously.

And I'm not sure which way you're looking at confidentiality concerns; if you mean it allows users to share information they wouldn't be able to share under their own names, *they shouldn't be doing that either way*.

> Avoid some 'discrimination' related to reputation. (Rarely, good questions get ignored or downvoted just because the user has very low reputation or because he's just new).

This is not my experience. Rather, I would say that new users are more likely to ask questions that do not meet SO's standards (partly because they are new, but there is plenty of help material many of them simply don't bother to read) whereas higher rep users know how the site works - this is correlation, not causation.

Comment: "Avoid some 'discrimination' ". just wondering why Philip Crow is getting so many downvotes while in the heat he just talked  nearly about the same idea as yours?

Comment: @εEridani: because Philip's answer was poorly written, the first 2 paragraphs didn't answer anything. Jon's answer is straightforward, straight to the point.

Comment: High rep users definitely know how the site works, they know just how to harvest as many upvotes as possible. You think high rep user don't post low quality, lazy answers ?

Comment: @JID I'm sure some do, and (as with questions) you should downvote them because they're low quality, irrespective of the rep of the poster. The downside of gamification is that there are usually ways to subvert the rules, however well-intentioned they are!